# Why does this string not change to uppercase?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

So I have a file of amino acids that I am trying to read `mdvfmkglskakegvvaaaektkqgvaeaagktkegvlyvgsktkegvvhgvatvaektk
eqvtnvggavvtgvtavaqktvegagsiaaatgfvkkdqlgkneegapqegiledmpvdp
dneayempseegyqdyepea`

and I have a list of uppercase letters called aminoacids. The problem is that I cannot read the sequence because the letters are lowercase. I have been trying to make it uppercase. There is no trouble reading the file and I thought I had successfully converted its contents into a string (but maybe I haven't?).

```
aminoacids = ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']
content1 = fh.readline() #first line, which is not the sequence
        #print content1
charline1 = len(content1)-1 #number of characters in the first line
        #print charline1
contentall = fh.readlines() #each line is converted into a string and put into a list
        #print contentall
numlines = len(contentall) #number of elements in list = number of lines, not the first one
        #print numlines
contentjoined = ''.join(contentall) #list elements are combined, but this includes new lines as characters
contentjoined = contentjoined.translate(None, "\n")
contentjoined = contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i not in aminoacids]))
contentjoined = contentjoined.upper()
print contentjoined
numaa = len(contentjoined)
print numaa #this shouldn't be zero but it is
```

Why does this not work? What can I do to fix it? I am in a `with` right now...that hasn't been a problem before, but is it now? Numaa is 0, when it shouldn't be. I realize that I can just add lowercase letters to my list but there should be a more "pythonic" way of fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because you are making your string uppercase after you are checking for the strings in `aminoacids`?  Try moving the `contentjoined = contentjoined.upper()` a line or two up.

When you check against `aminoacids`, you are supplying `str.translate` with a fully lowercase string, so it doesn't match the strings.  It ends up looking like this:

```
>>> c = contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i not in aminoacids]))
>>> c
''
```

If you call `upper` first, you'll be comparing an uppercase string with a list of uppercase strings, so you'll actually have matches.  It'll look like this:

```
>>> contentjoined = contentjoined.upper()
>>> c = contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i not in aminoacids]))
>>> c
'MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA'
```

If you want to keep the string as lowercase letters, you can just do the comparisons with uppercase letters and keep the lowercase letter.  That would look like this:

```
>>> c = contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined.upper() if i not in aminoacids]))
>>> c
'mdvfmkglskakegvvaaaektkqgvaeaagktkegvlyvgsktkegvvhgvatvaektkeqvtnvggavvtgvtavaqktvegagsiaaatgfvkkdqlgkneegapqegiledmpvdpdneayempseegyqdyepea'
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! My whole string was being changed to `None` because of that I think.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `translate()` commands:

```
contentjoined = contentjoined.translate(None, "\n")
contentjoined = contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i not in aminoacids]))
```

Here you are replacing everything found (well I am not sure what data you have in the `contentjoined` or `aminoacids` ) with `None` .
Like If you try:

```
>>>temp = "this is a test string"
>>>temp.translate(None, "aeiou")
>>>'ths s  tst strng' #THIS IS OUTPUT
```

So I am guessing your whole string is getting changed to  `None`.
Check out [translate() Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

Comment: Yes, you could think of it that way. The whole string is getting changed to `None` because it does not match any of the list elements. But the reason it doesn't match the list elements is because it is lowercase, which is why I asked about making it uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull in the file you could convert all the content to uppercase. Maybe something like this?

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().upper()

print(data)
'MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTK\nEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAPQEGILEDMPVDP\nDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA\n'
```